# two spans, one left aligned, one right aligned, both bottom aligned

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put two spans in a div, one on each side, and both aligned to the bottom of the div, without using absolute positioning (since that ignores padding, etc and I always feel bad after resorting to it).  The text in the right span is taller than in the left span.  If I use vertical-align to position them, it doesn't take affect if they are both floated, however without them both being floated, they will not be horiziontally aligned properly.  I don't have any guarantees on which of the two spans will have more text in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gsvfn07f/

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"> 
        <span class="left">left</span>
        <span class="right">right</span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>


.outer {
    width: 40%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.inner {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 5px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Do you require the widths of the 2 spans to be dynamic, or can they each be 50% of the div?

Comment: *"without using absolute positioning since that ignores padding"* Huh? Oh, the parent's padding.

Comment: what browser do you need to support? do you mean the bottom of the inner div or the outer div?

Comment: just Chrome, although other support is a plus.  I'd like the baseline of the text to be the bottom of the inner div, minus padding

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height` to get margin from top for your text.

This code seems to do what you want:

```css
.outer {
    width: 40%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.inner {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.left {
    line-height: 48px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.right {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"> 
        <span class="left">left</span>
        <span class="right">right</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: uses absolute positioning, and won't work if either of the text is larger than 50%

Comment: @zacaj yep, forgotten about this. Why you have this restrictions?

Comment: did you derive the line-height: 48px from the font-size: 2em or height: 35px in any way, or did you just adjust it pixel by pixel until it looked right?  After seeing this I thought that just setting the line height of .left to the font-size of .right would work, but they do not seem to correspond in any way I can see...

Comment: @zacaj Yes, I took a ruler and leaned it to the monitor:D

Comment: @zacaj it would be correct to use `position: absolute`, but you didn't give details why you can't use it

Comment: it ignores padding, and feels like a hack.  I realize CSS is one giant hack, but...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88739/discussion-between-aleshaoleg-and-zacaj).